# Drag Drop Win API 32

Tags: c++, api, winapi, ole

I'm trying to drag and drop a ListView item from my program to another (like dragging a path to something lie VLC, and it plays a video file). I'm using the CF_HDROP clipboard format. CopySelection is what sets the STGMEDIUM hglobal variable to a DROPFILES struct.

```
void CopySelection(HWND hwndList, STGMEDIUM &stgmed)
{
    HGLOBAL hMem;
    DROPFILES  *ptr;
    DROPFILES dfiles;
    POINT p;

    // get the selection inside the list control
    int iPos = SendMessage(hwndList, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, (WPARAM)-1,(LPARAM)LVNI_SELECTED);
    cout << "iPos: " << iPos << endl;
    LVITEM item;
    char buffer[256];
    string fileDir = "";
    item.iItem = iPos;
    item.iSubItem = 1;
    item.cchTextMax = 256;
    item.pszText = buffer;
    item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

    ListView_GetItem(hwndList, &item);
    fileDir += string(item.pszText);
    fileDir += "\\";
    item.iItem = iPos;
    item.iSubItem = 0;

    ListView_GetItem(hwndList, &item);
    fileDir += string(item.pszText);
    item.iItem = iPos;
    item.iSubItem = 2;

    ListView_GetItem(hwndList, &item);
    fileDir += string(item.pszText);

    cout << "fileDir: " << fileDir << endl;

    hMem = GlobalAlloc(GHND, sizeof(DROPFILES));
    ptr  = (DROPFILES *)GlobalLock(hMem);

    dfiles.fNC = TRUE;
    dfiles.fWide = FALSE;
    memcpy((void*)&dfiles.pFiles, (fileDir.c_str()+'\0'), fileDir.size()+1);

    GetCursorPos(&p);
    dfiles.pt=p;

    // copy the selected text and nul-terminate
    memcpy(ptr, (void*)&dfiles, sizeof(DROPFILES));

    GlobalUnlock(hMem);

    stgmed.hGlobal = hMem;

    //return hMem;
}
```

But this seems to cause a segfault. Here's the MouseMove list message code that calls it:

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    // stop drag-drop from happening when the mouse is released.
    if(fMouseDown)
    {
        IDataObject *pDataObject;
        IDropSource *pDropSource;
        DWORD        dwEffect;
        DWORD        dwResult;

        FORMATETC fmtetc = { CF_HDROP, 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL };
        STGMEDIUM stgmed = { TYMED_HGLOBAL   , { 0 }, 0 };

        // transfer the current selection into the IDataObject
        CopySelection(hwnd, stgmed);
        cout << "DO WE?" << endl;

        // Create IDataObject and IDropSource COM objects
        CreateDropSource(&pDropSource);
        CreateDataObject(&fmtetc, &stgmed, 1, &pDataObject);
        //
        //  ** ** ** The drag-drop operation starts here! ** ** **
        //
        //dwResult = DoDragDrop(pDataObject, pDropSource, DROPEFFECT_COPY|DROPEFFECT_MOVE, &dwEffect);
        dwResult = DoDragDrop(pDataObject, pDropSource, DROPEFFECT_COPY, &dwEffect);

        // success!
        if(dwResult == DRAGDROP_S_DROP)
        {
            if(dwEffect & DROPEFFECT_MOVE)
            {
                // remove selection from list control
            }
            else if(dwEffect & DROPEFFECT_LINK)
            {
            }
        }
        // cancelled
        else if(dwResult == DRAGDROP_S_CANCEL)
        {
        }

        pDataObject->Release();
        pDropSource->Release();

        ReleaseCapture();
        fMouseDown = FALSE;
        fDidDragDrop = TRUE;
    }
```

The code is properly formatted (I've checked) but unsure why this isn't working. Am I even using the right OLE clipboard format to make this happen? I'm unsure which to use and the documentation I've found isn't great.

Cheers,
Rob

P.S. I have tried to adapt this example:
http://www.catch22.net/tuts/drop-source

The difference is, he merely moves text, whereas I'm trying to move a list of files (like selecting icons in windows and dragging onto a vid player).

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and see where it crashes?

Comment: I'll try, but I use a try-catch exception loop with the path class in Boost::filesystem and for some damned reason the debugger that comes with Code:Blocks doesn't see me handling these exceptions so it stops on every directory I can't get access to (system dirs, usually). If anyone could help me with *that* too, it'd make this so much easier.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't like this line:
memcpy(ptr, (void*)&dfiles, sizeof(DROPFILES));
I'n trying to copy the DROPFILES struct to the HGLOBAL ptr I have.

Comment: The first `memcpy()` copied data to an invalid memory address, so the second `memcpy()` likely tried to access memory that was corrupted by the first `memcpy()`.

Answer (score 8):

You are not allocating enough memory for the `HGLOBAL` block.  You are allocating only enough memory to hold the `DROPFILES` itself, but no memory to hold the filename that goes with it. But even if you were allocating memory correctly, you are not using the `DROPFILES::pFiles` field correctly.  It needs to specify the offset from the start of the `DROPFILES` struct where the filename list begins, but you are treating it as a memory address instead.

Try this instead:

```
HGLOBAL CopySelection(HWND hwndList)
{
    // get the selection inside the list control

    int iPos = SendMessage(hwndList, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, (WPARAM)-1,(LPARAM)LVNI_SELECTED);
    if (iPos == -1)
        return NULL;

    cout << "iPos: " << iPos << endl;

    LVITEM item = {0};
    char buffer[256];
    string fileDir;

    item.cchTextMax = 256;
    item.pszText = buffer;
    item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

    item.iItem = iPos;
    item.iSubItem = 1;
    ListView_GetItem(hwndList, &item);
    fileDir = item.pszText;
    fileDir += "\\";

    item.iItem = iPos;
    item.iSubItem = 0;
    ListView_GetItem(hwndList, &item);
    fileDir += item.pszText;

    item.iItem = iPos;
    item.iSubItem = 2;
    ListView_GetItem(hwndList, &item);
    fileDir += item.pszText;

    cout << "fileDir: " << fileDir << endl;

    // +2 = the filename's null terminator and the file list's null terminator
    HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GHND, sizeof(DROPFILES) + fileDir.length() + 2);
    if (!hMem)
        return NULL;

    DROPFILES *dfiles = (DROPFILES*) GlobalLock(hMem);
    if (!dfiles)
    {
        GlobalFree(hMem);
        return NULL;
    }

    dfiles->pFiles = sizeof(DROPFILES);
    GetCursorPos(&(dfiles->pt));
    dfiles->fNC = TRUE;
    dfiles->fWide = FALSE;
    memcpy(&dfiles[1], fileDir.c_str(), fileDir.length());

    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    return hMem;
}
```

.

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    // stop drag-drop from happening when the mouse is released.
    if (fMouseDown)
    {
        IDataObject *pDataObject;
        IDropSource *pDropSource;
        DWORD        dwEffect;
        DWORD        dwResult;

        FORMATETC fmtetc = { CF_HDROP, 0, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL };
        STGMEDIUM stgmed = { TYMED_HGLOBAL   , { 0 }, 0 };

        // transfer the current selection into the IDataObject
        stgmed.hGlobal = CopySelection(hwnd);
        if (stgmed.hGlobal)
        {
            cout << "DO WE?" << endl;

            // Create IDataObject and IDropSource COM objects
            CreateDropSource(&pDropSource);
            CreateDataObject(&fmtetc, &stgmed, 1, &pDataObject);
            //
            //  ** ** ** The drag-drop operation starts here! ** ** **
            //
            //dwResult = DoDragDrop(pDataObject, pDropSource, DROPEFFECT_COPY|DROPEFFECT_MOVE, &dwEffect);
            dwResult = DoDragDrop(pDataObject, pDropSource, DROPEFFECT_COPY, &dwEffect);

            // success!
            if(dwResult == DRAGDROP_S_DROP)
            {
                if(dwEffect & DROPEFFECT_MOVE)
                {
                    // remove selection from list control
                }
                else if(dwEffect & DROPEFFECT_LINK)
                {
                }
            }
            // cancelled
            else if(dwResult == DRAGDROP_S_CANCEL)
            {
            }

            pDataObject->Release();
            pDropSource->Release();

            ReleaseCapture();
            fMouseDown = FALSE;
            fDidDragDrop = TRUE;
        }
    }
```

If you want to drag multiple selected files at a time, try this instead:

```
HGLOBAL CopySelection(HWND hwndList)
{
    vector<string> files;
    UINT len = 0;

    // get the selection inside the list control

    int iPos = -1;
    do
    {
        int iPos = SendMessage(hwndList, LVM_GETNEXTITEM, iPos, LVNI_SELECTED);
        if (iPos == -1)
            break;

        LVITEM item = {0};
        char buffer[256];
        string fileDir;

        item.cchTextMax = 256;
        item.pszText = buffer;
        item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;

        item.iItem = iPos;
        item.iSubItem = 1;
        ListView_GetItem(hwndList, &item);
        fileDir = item.pszText;
        fileDir += "\\";

        item.iItem = iPos;
        item.iSubItem = 0;
        ListView_GetItem(hwndList, &item);
        fileDir += item.pszText;

        item.iItem = iPos;
        item.iSubItem = 2;
        ListView_GetItem(hwndList, &item);
        fileDir += item.pszText;

        files.push_back(fileDir);

        // +1 = the filename's null terminator
        len += (fileDir.length() + 1);

        cout << "iPos: " << iPos << ", fileDir: " << fileDir << endl;
    }
    while (true);

    if (files.empty())
        return NULL;

    // +1 = the file list's null terminator
    HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GHND, sizeof(DROPFILES) + len + 1);
    if (!hMem)
        return NULL;

    DROPFILES *dfiles = (DROPFILES*) GlobalLock(hMem);
    if (!dfiles)
    {
        GlobalFree(hMem);
        return NULL;
    }

    dfiles->pFiles = sizeof(DROPFILES);
    GetCursorPos(&(dfiles->pt));
    dfiles->fNC = TRUE;
    dfiles->fWide = FALSE;

    char *pFile = (char*) &dfiles[1];
    for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i)
    {
        string &fileDir = files[i];

        // +1 = the filename's null terminator
        len = (fileDir.length() + 1);

        memcpy(pFile, fileDir.c_str(), len);
        pFile += len;
    }

    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    return hMem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!I am a little unsure of this though:

dfiles->pFiles = sizeof(DROPFILES);

That says 'look in memory after the size of this struct for our list of files', yes? But this:
memcpy(&dfiles[1], fileDir.c_str(), fileDir.length());
Copies the char* to right after the structure. I guess this is why my knowledge of C memory allocation falls flat - does &dfiles[1] refer to an array? If so, is it an array of dropfiles? But there's only DROPFILE and the length of the string (plus 2 chars) in the allocated memory.

Comment: Yes, that is what `dfiles->pFiles` refers to. The `&dfiles[1]` syntax is utilizing the fact that `dfiles` is a pointer by invoking pointer arithmetic to get the memory address that is exactly `1 * sizeof(DROPFILES)` number of bytes from the start of the allocated `DROPFILES ` struct. It could also be written as `(char*)(dfiles + 1)`, or longhanded as `(char*)(((LPBYTE)dfiles) + dfiles->pFiles)`, if you prefer.

Comment: Cheers for the explanation. I'm fine with an actual array of pointers, but it's the memory allocation that does my head in. :)

Comment: Hmm, still a problem though. I can't drag and drop from my listview onto another application. In the normal windows functionality, it brings the application you mouse over (on screen or on the toolbar) into focus so you can dump the filenames. Is this extra functionality I need to add myself?

Or do I need to set the window handle somewhere of the application I want to drag and drop to?

Comment: Neither. Windows handles everything for you. If you can't drag+drop, then either you did not implement `IDropSource` and/or `IDataObject` correctly, or the target app simply does not accept `CF_HDROP` or your `DROPEFFECT`.

Comment: Okay, I have VLC reacting to me dragging from my ListView to over it (ie, it's dragging and dropping something). But what comes up is gobbledyegook. So there are a couple of possibiities:
1. I'm not specifying the double-null terminated path string properly. I am trying to work out if escaped characters (\\) count as one or two characters in a string.
2. I've specified the wrong amount of memory for the string.
3. There's some sort of extra setting I'm not including.

Comment: You are allocating enough space for all of the null terminators and usin `GHND` to initialize them, so that is not an issue. `'\\'` literals count as one character in memory at runtime, so that is not an issue. So most likely, you are not providing the correct file path value(s), or VLC cannot access those files.

Comment: Hey again Remy,

The problem was how I was adding in the string literals (nulls). So I can drag and drop to every media player now (VLC, Media Player Class, even iTunes etc.) -EXCEPT Windows Media Player 10. I'm using all the drop_effects (which seems to allow the target to choose which works better - moving, copying or linking).

I suspect it may not work because I'm not displaying an icon as I drop and drag, or it requires something other then a CF_HDROP. Any takers?

Comment: Every app that supports filename drops should support `CF_HDROP`, since Microsoft sasys to. But when it doubt, try to support more formats. See [Shell Clipboard Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx) and [Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904.aspx).